# Moving paragraph element with hr next to image?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently stuck with this issue. I would like to have the hr element above my paragraph NEXT to the image. I'm having this issue where every time I try to display my hr element as inline-block it turns it into a really small dot and won't move to the side of the image and instead stays below (along with the paragraph) the image as if it is displaying as it is a block. If I delete the hr element, however, the paragraph will move to the side of the image. Even if I display my hr element as inline-block it doesn't help and actually makes matters worse. overflow: hidden; doesn't work either.

I'm trying to get a better understanding of code so this is a practice project that I am working on.

```css
.water-bottle {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 10px solid #01666d;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

main p {
  color: #00a4af;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  line-height: 40px;
}

hr {
  /* This makes the lines above the paragraphs */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #01666d;
  max-width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="main-page">
    <img src="images/Water/waterbottle.png" class="water-bottle">

    <p>
      <hr>In 2013, Americans ALONE generated about 254 million tons of trash. Could you imagine what the Earth will look like in 20-30 years if this continued year by year? Trash pollution is a serious issue. It will continue to be an issue until we step
      up and be concious of our daily behaviour. Which is why we decided to make a change NOW. Introducing, the 100% ECO friendly water bottle!
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: take the hr element out of the p tag. The hr element being the child may be the problem.

Comment: @DatBoiTrump That's how I get it to be above my text. When I take it out of the p tag, the hr element stays where it's at and pushes the p tag even further down, and to the right.

Comment: `position: fixed`

Comment: @RickyC While I have provided an answer below, one question that may be important to providing you with a better answer is "what is the purpose of the hr"?

Answer (score 0):

In order to line up the hr next to the img they must be in the same block-level parent. Placing the hr element in a `<p>` element places the `<hr>` in a completely different block-level parent from the image so they will not line up next to each other. I have removed the `<hr>` from the `<p>` element and have come up with the code below.

Your question, however, makes it a bit unclear how you want to line up the three objects: the image, the hr, and the paragraph. Have a look at what I have below. If this does not meet your requirements please re-specify what your requirements are:

```css
.water-bottle {
 height: 20%;
 width: 20%;
 border: 10px solid #01666d;
 border-radius: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 20%;
 display: inline-block;
 transform: rotate(25deg);
  vertical-align: middle;
    }

    main p {
 color: #00a4af;
 float: right;
 font-size: 15px;
 max-width: 30%;
 margin-right: 20%;
 margin-top: 15%;
 line-height: 40px;

    }

    hr { /* This makes the lines above the paragraphs */
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: #01666d;
        max-width: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        width: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="main-page">
    
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="water-bottle">
   <hr>
    <p>In 2013, Americans ALONE generated about 254 million tons of trash. Could you imagine what the Earth will look like in 20-30 years if this continued year by year?
    Trash pollution is a serious issue. It will continue to be an issue until we step up and be concious of our daily behaviour. Which is why we decided to make a change NOW. Introducing, the 100% ECO friendly water bottle!
    </p>
 </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Ok, I see how you got them side by side. You gave the image and p tag the property of vertical-align with the value of middle. It aligned on the middle axis of the parent <div> , right? I'm pretty new to this and am trying to get a better understanding. I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @RickyC, Yes, that is correct. The thing to note is that vertical-align can only be used with inline elements.

Comment: So things like imgs, and anchor tags are inline. And things like P tags, and header tags are block elements?

Comment: @RickyC Yes, that is correct. But changing p tags and header tags to inline-block makes them act as inline elements as well, so vertical-align will work with them as well. Also, while img elements are classified as inline for historical purposes, they do have some characteristics of inline-blocks (such as having a height and width).  But, yes, officially img elements are inline (just a bit different from most other inline elements).

Answer (score 0):

Try this hopefully It will work.

```html
<html> 
<head>
 <title>sample</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .img-section {
   width: 100%;

  }
  .water-bottle {
   height: 20%;
   width: 20%;
   border: 10px solid #01666d;
   border-radius: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-left: 15%;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-bottom: 20%;
   display: inline-block;
   transform: rotate(25deg);
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
  main p {
   color: #00a4af;
   float: right;
   font-size: 15px;
   max-width: 30%;
   margin-top: 15%;
   margin-right: 20%;
   line-height: 40px;
  }
  hr { 
   /* This makes the lines above the paragraphs */
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-color: #01666d;
      max-width: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
  <div class="main-page"> 
   <img src="images/Water/waterbottle.png" class="water-bottle">
   <hr>
      <p>In 2013, Americans ALONE generated about 254 million tons of trash. Could you imagine what the Earth will look like in 20-30 years if this continued year by year? Trash pollution is a serious issue. It will continue to be an issue until we step up and be concious of our daily behaviour. Which is why we decided to make a change NOW. Introducing, the 100% ECO friendly water bottle!</p>
  </div>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear. but still I have tried to given an answer. where the hr will be above the text but instead of a tiny line it'll will  have it's full width.
please let me know if it was of any help to you. Thank you :)

```css
.water-bottle {
height: 20%;
width: 20%;
border: 10px solid #01666d;
border-radius: 100%;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 15%;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 20%;
display: inline-block;
transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.text {
color: #00a4af;
float: right;
font-size: 15px;
max-width: 30%;
margin-right: 20%;
margin-top: 15%;
line-height: 40px;

}

hr { /* This makes the lines above the paragraphs */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #01666d;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <main>
  <div class="main-page">
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxjXlrA2C9ecV_2gNhFy4hD_PpQkNmNJSkzNyh87GVw434uFopEQ" class="water-bottle">
     <div class="text">
     <p>
      <hr />
      In 2013, Americans ALONE generated about 254 million tons of trash. Could you imagine what the Earth will look like in 20-30 years if this continued year by year?
      Trash pollution is a serious issue. It will continue to be an issue until we step up and be concious of our daily behaviour. Which is why we decided to make a change NOW. Introducing, the 100% ECO friendly water bottle!
     </p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </main>
```